# Style an activation indicator from material design

Tags: wpf, textbox, material-design, styling

I want to style an activation indicator from material design in WPF. I want the styling to happen in an external styling.xaml file, so the textbox I'm using can be binded to that style.

The textbox:

```
<TextBox  materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Search:" Grid.Column="1" Margin="35 8 20 5" 
Width="200" Style="{"STYLE style"}/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set it as a **StaticResource**:

File: *styling.xaml*

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNamespace">

   <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" x:key="YourCustomTextBoxStyle">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="35 8 20 5"/>
        ....
    </Style>    

</ResourceDictionary>
```

In your View (or Application) add a reference to the styling ResourceDictionary and use the style as a static resource:

```
<UserControl
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNamespace.Wpf"
            x:Class="YourView" mc:Ignorable="d">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/YourNamespace;component/Themes/styling.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <TextBox  materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Search:" Grid.Column="1" Width="200" Style="{StaticResource YourCustomTextBoxStyle}/>

</UserControl>
```